# requirement for pumping lemma in regular language

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am a bit confused on the theory of the pumping lemma. As I know is used to decide if a language is regular or not.

This is what I have understood so far though For a regular language $L$, there exists a $p > 0$ such that for all $w ∈ L$ where $|w| ≥ p$, there exists some split $w = vxu$, for which the following holds:

$|vx| ≤ p$

$|x| > 0$

$vx^iu ∈ L$ for all $i ≥ 0$

but what is the rationale behind the requirement of $|vx| ≤ p$ what happens if we drop that requirement??

thanks ahead

Comment: "As I know is used to decide if a language is regular or not." - No. PL is a _necessary_, but not _sufficient_ condition for the regularity of a language. So if a language does not satisfy the PL, it is not regular. But if it _does_ satisfy the PL, then it may still not be regular.

Comment: The constraint $|vx| \leq p$, which is necessary for the effectiveness of the lemma as showed by the answers, comes up directly out of the proof. Have you seen the proof of the pumping lemma?

Comment: I am confused; you say "I understood" and then cite the lemma. Have you read (and understood) the proof?

Answer (score 3):

$|vx| < p$ mean that $x$ is short and it is at the beginning of $w$. If you were to remove that constraint, all regular languages would still satisfy the lemma, but more irregular ones would too. For example $L = \{a^n \mid n ~\text {is not prime}\}$, when $n = m \cdot k $ can be pumped by taking $x = a^k$.